# How to reduce the frequency of /sidekiq/stats command invocations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

How to reduce the frequency of /sidekiq/stats command invocations when the Sidekiq dashboard is kept openend. Is there a way to set the frequency in which the /stats command should be fired.

```
Started GET "/sidekiq/stats" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-01-18 13:08:59 +0530
Started GET "/sidekiq/stats" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-01-18 13:09:04 +0530
Started GET "/sidekiq/stats" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-01-18 13:09:10 +0530
Started GET "/sidekiq/stats" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-01-18 13:09:14 +0530
Started GET "/sidekiq/stats" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-01-18 13:09:20 +0530
Started GET "/sidekiq/stats" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-01-18 13:09:24 +0530
Started GET "/sidekiq/stats" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-01-18 13:09:30 +0530
Started GET "/sidekiq/stats" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-01-18 13:09:34 +0530
Started GET "/sidekiq/stats" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-01-18 13:09:39 +0530
Started GET "/sidekiq/stats" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-01-18 13:09:44 +0530
Started GET "/sidekiq/stats" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-01-18 13:09:50 +0530
Started GET "/sidekiq/stats" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-01-18 13:09:54 +0530
Started GET "/sidekiq/stats" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-01-18 13:10:00 +0530
Started GET "/sidekiq/stats" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-01-18 13:10:04 +0530
Started GET "/sidekiq/stats" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-01-18 13:10:09 +0530
Started GET "/sidekiq/stats" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-01-18 13:10:14 +0530
Started GET "/sidekiq/stats" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-01-18 13:10:19 +0530
Started GET "/sidekiq/stats" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-01-18 13:10:24 +0530
Started GET "/sidekiq/stats" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-01-18 13:10:29 +0530
Started GET "/sidekiq/stats" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-01-18 13:10:34 +0530
Started GET "/sidekiq/stats" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-01-18 13:10:39 +0530
Started GET "/sidekiq/stats" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-01-18 13:10:44 +0530
Started GET "/sidekiq/stats" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-01-18 13:10:49 +0530
Started GET "/sidekiq/stats" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-01-18 13:10:54 +0530
Started GET "/sidekiq/stats" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-01-18 13:10:59 +0530
Started GET "/sidekiq/stats" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-01-18 13:11:04 +0530
Started GET "/sidekiq/stats" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-01-18 13:11:09 +0530
Started GET "/sidekiq/stats" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-01-18 13:11:14 +0530
Started GET "/sidekiq/stats" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-01-18 13:11:19 +0530
Started GET "/sidekiq/stats" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-01-18 13:11:24 +0530
Started GET "/sidekiq/stats" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-01-18 13:11:29 +0530
Started GET "/sidekiq/stats" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-01-18 13:11:34 +0530
Started GET "/sidekiq/stats" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-01-18 13:11:39 +0530
Started GET "/sidekiq/stats" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-01-18 13:11:44 +0530
Started GET "/sidekiq/stats" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-01-18 13:11:49 +0530
Started GET "/sidekiq/stats" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-01-18 13:11:54 +0530
Started GET "/sidekiq/stats" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-01-18 13:11:59 +0530
Started GET "/sidekiq/stats" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-01-18 13:12:04 +0530
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you see the "Polling Interval" slider?  Slide it.

Comment: Is there a way to configure this as a default for all users?